# ScrollViewer not enabled for ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, scrollview

I have a `ListView` control inside `UserControl`. But when content overflows size of the `ListView`, vertical `ScrollBar` is not enabled, despite of setting it in XAML.

[image]

XAML appears as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GrandSuccessProject.View.ContactsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="367" d:DesignWidth="548" Background="{x:Null}" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">

<ListView ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedContacts}"  
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}" 
          Grid.Row="1" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          VerticalContentAlignment="Top" />      
   
</UserControl>
```

I also tried grouping the `ListView` inside a `ScrollViewer`, but still doesn't work.

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: As i cannot reproduce this with the given code, could you perhaps construct an example which does? If you try to boil it down you might even notice where the problem lies on your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like

1. The ListView taking all the space it needs for all the items, hence the scrolling is disabled.
2. The ListView exceeding its container's bounds.

So i would assume that the container is at fault for not restricting the size of the ListView, where did you place it? Make sure the container lays out the controls with limitations.

Comment: You are absolutely right, if I keep a fix pixel height for ListView, the scrollbar works.

Comment: @Marshal: Something is wrong but it's hard to tell without all the context, what properties are set on the UserControl?

Comment: @Marshal: See edit, haven't tested it yet but i suspected that you did something like this and it might just be the problem...

Comment: I tried removing VerticalContentAlignment property, but still no effect

Comment: @Marshal: Well, obviously the design heights do restrict the size and can cause overflows, but this also fails at runtime, doesn't it?

Comment: I mean, if I set restrict the height of ListView for lets say "150", it works, the scrollbar is enabled.

Comment: @Marshal: Yes, as i said the size of the ListView needs to be restricted, usually the container will do that by default. Sorry, i am quite at a loss here...

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it passing the Height and Width from the MainWindow to the Usercontrol:

```
 <UC:UC Width="{Binding ElementName=GridMainWindow, Path=ActualWidth}" 
    Height="{Binding ElementName=GridMainWindow, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
```

And inside the usercontrol i defined a Gridview like this:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> <!--This inherith from the window-->
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```