# WPF ListView does not keep the items into view when swiped

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, swipe

I have a Windows 8.1 Store application and in one of the views, I have a ListView that displays some items. Not all the items fit into the area where the ListView is displayed (inside a StackPanel). If I swipe up I get to see some of the items listed towards the bottom of my list, but those items do not stay into view. As soon as I release the list, it scrolls up again so that the first item in the list is listed at the top of the list. How can I prevent this annoying behavior? This is how my ListView is declared:

```
<ListView Name="ParametersListView" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source = {StaticResource parametersViewSource}}"
          SelectionMode="Single" IsSwipeEnabled="True" IsItemClickEnabled="False">
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out what the problem was, though I have no explanation for it. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066497/scrollviewer-not-enabled-for-listview) on StackOverflow and according to one suggestion made there, if the container that holds the ListView does not restrict the size of the ListView control, then you can't scroll down the ListView. My ListView was placed in a vertical StackPanel but once I changed that and placed it into a Grid, all was fine. I set the Height for the Row where I placed the ListView to "*". My Grid has one other row that contains the header of the ListView.

Before, when the ListView was placed in a StackPanel, I didn't set the Height of the StackPanel and maybe that is why the behavior was the way it was.

This [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221813/wpf-listview-no-scrollbar-if-height-set-to-auto) has more details and the first answer contains a detailed explanation of the issue.